# Disassembling a Java code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Reading a Apache Crunch example which is mostly Java and being new to both. (I know .NET)
So here is the sample code:

```
DoFn<String, Pair<String, Long>> extractIPResponseSize = new DoFn<String, Pair<String, Long>>() {
  transient Pattern pattern;
  public void initialize() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(logRegex);
  }
  public void process(String line, Emitter<Pair<String, Long>> emitter) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
      try {
        Long responseSize = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(7));
        String remoteAddr = matcher.group(1);
        emitter.emit(Pair.of(remoteAddr, responseSize));
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // corrupt line, we should increment a counter
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The first line very confuses me and I can't follow it, can you explain it piece by piece? 
Note: `DoFn` is a class in Apache Crunch and here is the documentaiotn for that:
http://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.3.0/org/apache/crunch/DoFn.html

I also did some Googling and looks like `Pair` is also a Apache common Lang thing in here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

Maybe it is Java generics that I need to understand?

Comment: You need to learn about generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoFn` is a generic class. That is, each instance of it contains type arguments. The type arguments are used within the method, but are replaced by the compiler with `Object` references. For more about generics, see [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Generics).

As for the opening brace after that line, that is a subtle reminder that this is actually an inner class being declared. It is an anonymous subclass of `DoFn` that overrides the `initialize` and `process` methods. For more about inner classes, see [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes) again.